# Navigation Bar - child elements do not inheriting width and overlapping

Tags: css

so I'm learning CSS and trying to build my own navbar, but I am having some trouble to align the childs.

There are basically two problems:

1. The elements are overlapping
2. The child element bar is not taking the width of the parent. The image below can illustrate both problems:

[image: navigation bar problems]

Btw, if you guys can see problems with my code beyond the ones that I mentioned above, feel free to point it out.

Here is the code:

```css
body{
    background-color: rgb(210,210,210);
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

nav{
    background-color: rgb(97, 97, 97);
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    display: flex;
}

#Logo{
    width: 20%;
    height: inherit;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

#Logo p{
    /*font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande';*/
    font-size: 120%;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

#Hyperlinks{
    width: 80%;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}

#Hyperlinks ul{
    padding-inline-start: 0;
}

#Hyperlinks li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#Hyperlinks a{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

#Hyperlinks>ul>li>a{
    border-right:solid white 3px;
}

#Hyperlinks>ul>li:hover {
    background-color: rgb(27, 129, 107);
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
}

#Hyperlinks ul li li:hover{
    background-color: rgb(27, 129, 107);
}

#Hyperlinks ul ul{
    display: none;
}


#Hyperlinks li:hover ul{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
}


#Hyperlinks li:hover li{
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(97, 97, 97);
    
}

section{
    padding: 0 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Navigation Bar 3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gabarito.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div id="Logo">
                <p>MySite.com</p>
            </div>
            <div id="Hyperlinks">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tutorial</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Tutorial 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Tutorial 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Tutorial 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- repare onde o li é quebrado... esse ul fica dentro dele, filho msm -->
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">News 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">News 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">News 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>
    </header>
    <section>
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <p>Hello, it`s just a test. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, temporibus, culpa.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, temporibus, culpa! Impedit amet voluptates reiciendis esse quisquam. Eum quia, facere laboriosam quos possimus, ratione, optio incidunt sunt dolorum commodi magni.</p>
    </section>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `width: 100%` instead of `width: inherit;`, and use a `top: XXpx` setting on the absolutely positioned sub menu `ul` to move it down in relation to its parent.

(and don't forget that the parent of an absolutely positioned element needs to have `position: relative`in order to serve as an anchor for its child.)

Comment: Hey, firstly , thanks!!
So I've changed 

#Hyperlinks li:hover ul{
    top: 68px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

Solved the overlapping problem, but the width 100% didn't solve the other problem =(
Also I didn't understand quite well where should I insert the "position: relative" element.

Comment: `position: relative`should be applied to the `li` main navigation items which contain `ul` submenus. So that would be `#Hyperlinks > ul > li  { position: relative; }`